# Python looping to read and parse all in a directory

Tags: python, xml, file-io, blogs

```
class __init__:
    path = "articles/"
    files = os.listdir(path)
    files.reverse()

    def iterate(Files, Path):

        def handleXml(content):

            months = ['', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

            parse = re.compile('<(.*?)>(.*?)<(.*?)>').findall(content)
            day = parse[1][1]
            month = months[int(parse[2][1])]
            dayN = parse[3][1]
            year = parse[4][1]
            hour = parse[5][1]
            min = parse[6][1]
            amPM = parse[7][1]
            title = parse[9][1]
            author = parse[10][1]
            article = parse[11][1]
            category = parse[12][1]

        if len(Files) > 5:
            del Files[5:]

        for file in Files:
            file = "%s%s" % (Path, file)
            f = open(file, 'r')
            handleXml(f.read())
            f.close()

    iterate(files, path)
```

It runs on start, and if I check the files array it contains all the file names.
But when I loop through them they just do not work, only displays the first one.
If I return file I only get the first two, and if I return parse even on duplicate files it is not identical.
None of this makes any sense.

I am trying to make a simple blog using Python, and because my server has a very old version of Python I cannot use modules like glob, everything needs to be as basic as possible.

The files array contains all the files in the directory, which is good enough for me. I do not need to go through other directories inside the articles directory.

But when I try to output parse, even on duplicate files I get different results.

Thanks,

- Tom

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't call the iterate() function, and doesn't print anything out.  Please post the complete code.

Comment: Also, the indenting looks wrong, which is obviously very important in Python.  Please try to fix it so it looks exactly as it does in your text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be because of:

```
del Files[5:]
```

It deletes the last 5 entries from the original list as well. Instead of using `del`, you can try:

```
for file in Files[:5]:
  #...
```

Comment: Did not work, but nice way to remove two lines and preserve original array.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, the actual recursion is missing.
Even if it is there in some other place of the code, the recursion call is the typical place where the things are wrong, and for this reason I would suggest you to double check it.

However, why don't you use [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk)? It iterates through all the path, without the need of reinventing the (recursive) wheel. It has been introduced in 2.3, though, and I do not know how old your python is.

Comment: my array is not the issue, it is something else. If I print the array it shows all files.

Comment: Can you please check the length of the array? I am asking because there could be the chance you have an array of 1-2 string elements with all file names separated by spaces.